# What can cause "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" in a prepared query?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

This is in Cassandra 3.11.4.

I'm running a modified version of a query that previously worked fine in my app. The original query that is fine was like:

```
SELECT SerializedRecord FROM SxRecord WHERE Mark=?
```

I modified the query to have a range of a timestamp (which I also added an index for, though I don't think that is relevant):

```
SELECT SerializedRecord FROM SxRecord WHERE Mark=? AND Timestamp>=? AND Timestamp<=?
```

This results in:

```
 ResponseError {reHost = datacenter1:rack1:127.0.0.1:9042, reTrace = Nothing, reWarn = [], reCause = ServerError "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1"}
```

When this occurs, I don't see the query CQL being logged in `system_traces.sessions`, which is interesting, because if I put a syntax error into the query, it is still logged there.

Additionally, when I run an (as far as I know, identical, up to timestamps) query in cqlsh, there doesn't seem to be a problem:

```
cqlsh> SELECT SerializedRecord FROM test_fds.SxRecord WHERE Mark=8391 AND Timestamp >= '2021-03-06 00:00:00.000+0000' AND Timestamp <= '2021-03-09 00:00:00.000+0000';

 serializedrecord
------------------
```

This results in the following query trace:

```
cqlsh> select parameters from system_traces.sessions;

 parameters
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {'consistency_level': 'ONE', 'page_size': '100', 'query': 'SELECT SerializedRecord FROM test_fds.SxRecord WHERE Mark=8391 AND Timestamp >= ''2021-03-06 00:00:00.000+0000'' AND Timestamp <= ''2021-03-09 00:00:00.000+0000'';', 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL'}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the query, executed inside a prepared/bound statement, is not recieving all the parameters needed OR too many (something bound in previous code)

The fact that you don't see the query traced comes from the fact that the driver does not even perform the query as it has unbound parameters

Comment: That make sense. I just traced that I'm sending all 3 arguments to the prepared statement, so it might be a bug in the driver pertaining to the timestamps. However, the same driver is able to insert timestamps without issue.

Comment: As it turns out, this lead me in the right direction - the driver API I used was heavily typed, but, it can't actually verify the types are correct in all cases. In my cases, I was using a type that specified 1 query parameter when in fact I had 3.